# MSP430, how can I put it in sleep mode for 20 mins?

Tags: msp430, texas-instruments, sleep-mode

I'm working on an assignment. Can someone help me with this? 
How to put MSP430 to sleep for 20 mins and rise an interrupt after that ?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

If this acceptable for your assignment, I would use a timer that wakes the MSP every 1 sec or so (ex: timerA in up mode on LFXT1 with a 32kHz quartz, with interrupt on TACCR0 value 32767).

Then you can use a counter or timekeeper to know when your 20 minutes are done.